# New netstat Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: netstat

I have been using netstat 1.42 without any problem but yesterday I installed a fresh VPS and when I try to set commands netstat does not show anything.

I use this command to see all active TCP connections:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80| awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq | sort -nr | paste -sd, -
```

When I check the version I see the version 2.10-alpha. How do I change to the 1.42 version or what has changed on this new version?

I'm new in this

Answer (score 0):

you can install specific version of any package with apt

```
apt-cache policy packages
```

output sample for net-tools :

```
net-tools:
  Installed: 1.60-26ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.60-26ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.60-26ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

run this command to find all the available version of a package then choose your favorite version and install it with bellow command

```
sudo apt install packages=version
```

example usage for net-tools :

```
sudo apt install net-tools=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: mm it says `net-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
`
but i want this:
`net-tools:
  Installed: 1.60-26ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.60-26ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.60-26ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`
or what i have to change in my command to get the same output?

Comment: replace this repository `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main` in  `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main` and  run `sudo apt update` finally try again

Comment: i have this http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main on this file

Comment: nop add or replace new repository `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main` and do stuff

Comment: still install 2.10 alpha

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OkDFcWX.png this is de source.list